# Data from dataflow is not showing in datasets

Tags: data, analytics, einstein-analytics

Even though my data flow is successfully updated and shows by a green box and a tick mark. I am unable to see that file in the datasets. I have tried refreshing as well. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Are you registering your dataset?

After all your extraction and transformation you have to register the last step in order to actually create the Dataset.

Make sure you have a node like this in your dataflow:

```
"Register_Dataset_Node": {
    "action": "sfdcRegister",
    "parameters": {
      "name": "Dataset Label",
      "alias": "Dataset_API_Name",
      "source": "name_of_your_last_node"
    }
  },
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- If you have registered and still not able to see the dataset.Then check if you have ran the dataflow and it should be successful.Then you should be able to see.

  - Still if you can't find.Please check input and output row results of the dataflow in monitor.Please check the warnings and.If there is no data in dataset ,then it would not be available on UI.
  - Ref:https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250116&type=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a replication issue? Did you check that?

If you have replication enabled, first you should go to **'Setup'** under **'Data Manager'** then run the replication on enabled Salesforce objects.

After that try running your 'Dataflow' again.