# Unable to create dataset in Wave Analytics Dataset Builder

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

Can anyone help to shed some light on my issue? I have created the custom object called 'Iris__c' in Salesforce (Dev edition). The obj contains 149 records. What I am puzzled about now is that when I try to create a dataset in Wave Analytics for the custom object, I am unable to pick it from object selection popup in Dataset builder.

Here is what I have done/confirmed so far.

1. Dataflow Definition File

> {
>     "Extract_Iris": {
>         "action": "sfdcDigest",
>         "parameters": {
>            "object": "Iris__c",
>            "fields": [
>               { "name": "Id" },
>               { "name": "Name" },
>               { "name": "PetalLength__c" },
>               { "name": "PetalWidth__c" },
>               { "name": "SepalLength__c" },
>               { "name": "SepalWidth__c" },
>               { "name": "IrisClass__c" }
>            ]
>         }
>      }
>   }

2. the job to load the records was successfully finished indicating that input/output rows were 149.
   [image]
3. I cant see 'Iris'(custom object name I've created) in object selection.
   [image]

Comment: Hi try to go through some of the free courses on Trailhead - https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/wave_analytics_basics - Babu Kannan

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from Vrakmhare's post here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/119909/24202

The thing is Dataflow's json file needs to have two kinds of nodes - to digest sf records and to register them.

My json file now looks like this.
[image]

After a successful reload, now I can see dataset created.
[image]
[image]